For and end for alignment in algorithmic
I have been writing my research and had to use a lot of algorithm inserts, and I haven't worked with it enough to solve this issue. My For and EndFor part don't seem to align no matter what.
I tried removing the lines, removing the algorithmic environment (it helped, but it looked weird with all the bold lines one after the other). Could you help me, please?
The code is below, I redefined some of the names to fit my native language, but I translated it back in English just for it to be more understandable.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{KwData}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwResult}{Ensure}
\SetKw{KwTo}{to}
\SetKwFor{For}{For}{do}{end for}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{a reduced basis 
 $\left\{\mathbf{b}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b}_{d}\right\}$ 
 of $L$, and a target vector $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbf{R}^{d}$}
 \KwResult{the ouput lattice vector $\mathbf{u} \in L$ is 'close' to $\mathbf{t}$}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\mathbf{S} \leftarrow \mathbf{t}$
    \State \For{$i = d$ \KwTo  $1$} {
        $\mathbf{s} \leftarrow \mathbf{s}-\lambda \mathbf{b}_{i}$, where $\lambda=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\mathbf{s} \cdot \mathbf{b}_{i}^{*}\right)} {\left(\mathbf{b}_{i}^{*} \cdot \mathbf{b}_{i}^{*}\right)}\right\rceil$
}
    \State $\mathbf{u} \leftarrow \mathbf{t}-\mathbf{s}$
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Babai's nearest plane algorithm}
\label{alg:the_alg}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}



Can you provide a complete MWE that is compiling without any errors and produces the above issue?

My guess is that you are mixing commands from various packages. Also, there should not be any \State command before \For.

Given that there are multiple package for algorithm which are partially incompatible with each other, we really need to see a compilable test file to make sure that any answer you might get will actually work for you.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited the problem to include a complete code

@codeR if the \State command is deleted, then everything becomes even worse with line not breaking before For

That is because each \State or line must be manually ended with \\  or something similar. See the detailed answer given by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz below.

You are mixing the syntax of different algorithm environments. The algorithmic environment and \State come from the algpseudocode package. However in this package a for-loop would be \For ... \EndFor.

If you use the \For{...}{...}, stick to the algorithm2e syntax:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{KwData}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwResult}{Ensure}
\SetKw{KwTo}{to}
\SetKwFor{For}{For}{do}{end for}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwData{%
    a reduced basis 
    $\left\{\mathbf{b}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b}_{d}\right\}$ 
    of $L$, and a target vector $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbf{R}^{d}$
  }
  \KwResult{%
    the ouput lattice vector $\mathbf{u} \in L$ is 'close' to 
    $\mathbf{t}$
  }
  $\mathbf{S} \leftarrow \mathbf{t}$\;
  \For{%
    $i = d$ \KwTo  $1$
  }{%
    $\mathbf{s} \leftarrow \mathbf{s}-\lambda \mathbf{b}_{i}$, where $\lambda=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\mathbf{s} \cdot \mathbf{b}_{i}^{*}\right)} {\left(\mathbf{b}_{i}^{*} \cdot \mathbf{b}_{i}^{*}\right)}\right\rceil$
  }
  $\mathbf{u} \leftarrow \mathbf{t}-\mathbf{s}$\;
  \caption{Babai's nearest plane algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}



oh, I see, thank you so much for your help!

@Ксения You're welcome!

It seems your problem has been resolved. @Ксения kindly accept this solution to close this post.
